# SAX Parser: How to read only from `Item` tag?

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

I am using SAX Parser to parse some XML content. Please check my code below.

```
 public void parse(InputSource is, AppDataBean appDataBean) throws RuntimeException {

        int limitCheck;

        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            Log.d("SAX",appDataBean.getUrl());


            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                boolean title = false;
                boolean link = false;
                boolean author = false;

                public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                                         String qName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)) {
                        title = true;
                    }

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)) {
                        link = true;
                    }

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(AUTHOR)) {
                        author = true;
                    }


                    //Log.d("SAX","Start Element :" + qName);



                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                                       String qName)
                        throws SAXException {




                }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                        throws SAXException {

                    System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));


                    if (title) {
                        Log.d("SAX","End Element :" + "First Name : "
                                + new String(ch, start, length));

                        title = false;
                    }

                    if (link) {


                        Log.d("SAX","End Element :" + "Last Name : "
                                + new String(ch, start, length));
                        link = false;
                    }

                    if (author) {

                        Log.d("SAX","End Element :" + "Nick Name : "
                                + new String(ch, start, length));

                        author = false;
                    }

                }

            };

            saxParser.parse(is, handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Below is how my XML will look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="rss.xsl"?>
   <channel>
      <title>MyRSS</title>
      <atom:link href="http://www.example.com/rss.php" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
      <link>http://www.example.com/rss.php</link>
      <description>MyRSS</description>
      <language>en-us</language>
      <pubDate>Tue, 22 May 2018 13:15:15 +0530</pubDate>
      <item>
         <title>Title 1</title>
         <pubDate>Tue, 22 May 2018 13:14:40 +0530</pubDate>
         <link>http://www.example.com/news.php?nid=47610</link>
         <guid>http://www.example.com/news.php?nid=47610</guid>
         <description>bla bla bla</description>
      </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

However in here, I nee to avoid the `Channel` tag and only read of the root tag is `Item`. Then only I can get the real content. How can I do this?

**Update**

As suggested by an answer, I tried using the SAX Parser with `stack`. Below is the code but still I no good, now it prints nothing for the `First Name`

```
public void parse(InputSource is,  AppDataBean appDataBean) throws RuntimeException {

        int limitCheck;
        stack = new Stack<>();


        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            Log.d("SAX", appDataBean.getUrl());


            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                boolean title = false;
                boolean link = false;
                boolean author = false;

                public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                                         String qName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {

                    Log.d("SAX", "localName: " + localName);

                    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                    {
                        stack = new Stack<>();
                        stack.push(qName);
                    }


                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)) {
                        if(stack.peek().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                        {
                            title = true;
                        }

                    }

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)) {
                        link = true;
                    }

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(AUTHOR)) {
                        author = true;
                    }


                    //Log.d("SAX","Start Element :" + qName);


                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                                       String qName)
                        throws SAXException {

                    stack.pop();
                }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                        throws SAXException {

                    System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));


                    if (title) {
                        Log.d("SAX", "End Element :" + "First Name : "
                                + new String(ch, start, length));

                        title = false;
                    }

                    if (link) {


                        Log.d("SAX", "End Element :" + "Last Name : "
                                + new String(ch, start, length));
                        link = false;
                    }

                    if (author) {

                        Log.d("SAX", "End Element :" + "Nick Name : "
                                + new String(ch, start, length));

                        author = false;
                    }

                }

            };

            saxParser.parse(is, handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically a SAX application will maintain a stack to hold context. On a startElement event, push the element name to the stack; on endElement pop it off the stack. Then when you get a startElement event for a title element, you can do stack.peek() to see what the parent of the title is.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you provide an example?

Comment: No, SAX code is low-level and hard to write and if you choose to use such a low-level programming interface then you're going to have to do the hard work yourself.

Comment: I chose it because of the speed. The DOM took nearly 2 seconds to parse an article, while sax seems much faster.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and updated my question with the new code. I still have no good. Can you please check?

Comment: You shouldn't create a new stack when you encounter an item element, and you should stack every element name encountered, not just items. If you only stack items, then the top element on the stack will always be an item.